# Change date format for Yii dateField

Tags: php, date, yii, datepicker

I want to display the date picker in Yii and get the date in "YYYY-MM-DD" format so that I can save in my DB. I have used the following code but it gives the date in "MM/DD/YYYY" format which throws error while saving in database as this is not the date.

View code:

```
<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'datecreated'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->dateField($model,'datecreated'); ?>

    <?php echo $form->error($model,'datecreated'); ?>
</div>
```

Modal code:

```
<?php

public function tableName()
{
    return 'admin';
}

public function rules()
{

    return array(
        array('datecreated', 'type', 'type' => 'date', 'message' => '{attribute}: is not a date!','dateFormat'=>'YYYY-MM-DD'),
        array('datecreated','safe', 'on'=>'search'),
    );
}

public function attributeLabels()
{
    return array(
        'datecreated' => 'Birthdate',
    );
}

public function search()
{

    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->compare('datecreated',$this->datecreated,true);

    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
    ));
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `beforeSave` function in your model:

```
protected function beforeSave()
{
    // convert when storing in db
    $this->datecreated = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($this->datecreated));

    return parent::beforeSave();
}
```

And if you want to display the date in mm/dd/yyyy format then use `afterFind` function in your model:

```
protected function afterFind()
{
    // convert the date back to mm/dd/yyyy format while viewing
    $this->datecreated = date('m/d/Y', strtotime($this->datecreated));

    parent::afterFind();
}
```

Or, you could convert the date format in your controller before `$model->save();`:

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Admin();
    if(isset($_POST['Admin']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['Admin'];
        $model->datecreated = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($model->datecreated));
        ......
        $model->save();
        ......
    }
    ......
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use CJuiDatePicker widget:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker', array(
    'model'=>$model,
    'attribute'=>'datecreated',
    // jQuery datepicker plugin options
    'options' => array(
        'showAnim' => 'fold',
        'dateFormat'=>'yyyy-mm-dd',
    ),
    'htmlOptions' => array(
     ),
));
```

Also you can add validation rule, using  CDateValidator:

```
public function rules()
{

    return array(
        array('datecreated', 'date', 'format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd', 'allowEmpty' => false),
        array('datecreated','safe', 'on'=>'search'),
    );
}
```

Thanks.